# Laravel 4.2 , Model (eloquent) my own class not found

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have this weird error ... I apparently cannot use any of my model class in my project..
Ad_category model

```
class Ad_category extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'ad_category';
    protected $fillable = array('*');
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

calling this

```
$ad_cat=Ad_category::find(1);
```

error

```
`Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Class 'Ad_category' not found `
```

Comment: I don't see `Ad_target` anywhere in your question except the error message...

Comment: oops sorry @lukasgeiter ad_target or category i am getting same error

Comment: What is the namespace for this class? What autoloading scheme are you using? Have you tried `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: no name space is being used..
and its default autoload scheme... and let me try dump autoload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP frameworks use a system called "autoloading" to automatically `include` or `require` in the correct class definition file when you want to use a class.  Autoloading in Laravel 4.2 is in a bit of a [transitional spot](http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#autoloading), which means there's multiple answers to your question.

By default, Laravel 4.2 will look for a class named `Ad_category` in one of the following four locations.

```
app/commands/Ad/category.php
app/controllers/Ad/category.php
app/models/Ad/category.php
app/database/seeds/Ad/category.php
```

That is, Laravel's autoloader will automatically convert `Ad_category` into the file path `Ad/category.php`, and then check each configured autoload path for that file.  You can configure the base autoloader paths in

```
#File: app/start/global.php
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
));
```

Laravel 4.2 also uses composer based autoloading. Specifically, is uses a very aggressive form of composer autoloading called `classmap` autoloading.  If you look in your `composer.json` file, you'll see a section like this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
```

When you manually run the command

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

Composer will go through every folder in the above section and look for PHP class files.  If it finds one, it adds it to the classmap in `vendor/composer/autoload_classes.php`.  Composer also runs this command automatically during updates.

So, what this means is, if you've defined `Ad_category` in a different location than Laravel expects to find it, you may be able to get away with running

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

and Laravel will use Composer's autoloader to find your class.